# taking top 3 in a groupby, and lumping rest into 'other category'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am currently doing a groupby in pandas like this:

```
df.groupby(['grade'])['students'].nunique())
```

and the result I get is this:

```
grade
grade 1                      12
grade 2                       8
grade 3                      30
grade 4                       2
grade 5                     600
grade 6                      90
```

Is there a way to get the output such that I see the groups of the top 3, and everything else is classified under other?

this is what I am looking for

```
grade
grade 3                      30
grade 5                     600
grade 6                      90
other (3 other grades)       22
```

Comment: Can you please post the initial dataset that gives you the output so that the input is reproducible for others?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a helper column in the df and call it something like "Grouping".
name the top 3 rows with its original name and name the remaining as "other" and then just group by the "Grouping" column.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do much without the actual input data, but if this is your starting dataframe `(df)` after your groupby -

```
     grade  unique
0  grade_1      12
1  grade_2       8
2  grade_3      30
3  grade_4       2
4  grade_5     600
5  grade_6      90
```

You can do a few more steps to get to your table -

```
ddf = df.nlargest(3, 'unique')
ddf = ddf.append({'grade': 'Other', 'unique':df['unique'].sum()-ddf['unique'].sum()}, ignore_index=True)
```

```
     grade  unique
0  grade_5     600
1  grade_6      90
2  grade_3      30
3    Other      22
```